# Why does GNU head/tail read the whole file?

Tags: tail, gnu, head

I have a huge file and want to see its beginning and end. However, when I use `head` and `tail`, it apparently tries to read the whole file. Since the file is larger than a terabyte, this takes a very long time. Why would the tools do the simple task in such an inefficient way? Is there a reasonable workaround?

The command I'm running is simple `tail filename`

Edit: Since the question was marked as duplicate, I cannot post a proper answer.

**The real reason why `head` and `tail` were reading the whole file was that the file contained no newline characters. There is a nice workaround by PM 2Ring - using the `-c` option and piping the output to `hexdump`.**

Comment: What is the exact command that you're running?

Comment: It doesn't, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102907/79979

Comment: I would be inclined to believe that if the command wasn't running for two hours already.

Comment: Is it possible that that file contains very few newline characters (very few lines)? Is it a regular file? What file system is it on?

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right! It's just a test file full of zeroes. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: So you can still look at your binary file efficiently (or newline-free text file) using head or tail by supplying a byte **c**ount with the `-c` option. Of course, you may want to pipe the output through hexdump or similar. :)